# Сверстать кнопку

Tags: css

Как сверстать такую кнопку?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал box-shadow, но не то.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Просто:

```
border-bottom: 3px solid #C86A40;
border-radius: 3px;
```

Значения примерные.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 5):

Можно снизу ещё один элемент добавить (например, div) и у него прописать 
`border-bottom-left-radius` и `border-bottom-right-radius`, тем самым закруглив снизу границу нижнего элемента, получится тоже самое. [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Sysanin/v879uty0/1/)

```css
#top{
    height:200px;
    background:#990099;
    color:white;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

#bottom{
    height:5px;
    background:#770077;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"> Button </div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Зачем говнокодить? Тут вполне можно и без лишнего `div` обойтись, тем более в таком случае ещё придётся в раппер заворачивать всё чтобы не распалось.

Comment: Согласен, что вставка лишнего элемента в вёрстку для такой задачи - это в каком-то смысле дикость, и в конечном счёте это надо тоже учитывать. Но способ имеет место быть :)

Comment: Тогда можно ещё пару дивов засунуть - на уголки, их превратить в круги, позиционировать по углам, так сказать.

Comment: и между этими уголками пустить картинку с шириной 1px и repeat-x сделать, самый сок! :)

Comment: Да это для младенцев - настоящий мужЫк сделает много `div` шириной в пиксель!